# Upgrade Ubuntu 11.10 to 12.04: Apache not working anymore

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, windows-authentication

I upgraded Ubuntu Server from 11.10 to 12.04 LTS. Now Apache is not working properly anymore. I'm using the module AuthenNTLM and that seems to be causing the issue. Apache Error log:

```
[1556] AuthenNTLM: Config Domain = myDomain  pdc = myDomainServerName  bdc = myDomainServerName
[1556] AuthenNTLM: Config Default Domain = myDomain
[1556] AuthenNTLM: Config Fallback Domain = 
[1556] AuthenNTLM: Config AuthType = ntlm AuthName = XYZ Protected Access
[1556] AuthenNTLM: Config Auth NTLM = 1 Auth Basic = 0
[1556] AuthenNTLM: Config NTLMAuthoritative = on  BasicAuthoritative = on
[1556] AuthenNTLM: Config Semaphore key = 23754 timeout = 2
[1556] AuthenNTLM: Config SplitDomainPrefix = 
[1556] AuthenNTLM: Authorization Header <not given>
[Wed May 02 14:45:40 2012] [error] Bad/Missing NTLM/Basic Authorization Header for /MyApp/searchForm.php
[1556] AuthenNTLM: Start NTLM Authen handler pid = 1556, connection = 3076026864 conn_http_hdr = keep-alive  main =  cuser =  remote_ip = 192.168.213.2 remote_port = 12851 remote_host = <> version = 0.02 smbhandle = 
[1556] AuthenNTLM: Object exists user = \
[1556] AuthenNTLM: Authorization Header NTLM
[1556] AuthenNTLM: protocol=NTLMSSP, type=1, flags1=7(NEGOTIATE_UNICODE,NEGOTIATE_OEM,REQUEST_TARGET), flags2=178(NEGOTIATE_ALWAYS_SIGN,NEGOTIATE_NTLM), domain length=5, domain offset=50, host length=10, host offset=40, host=CLDM2345, domain=myDomain
[1556] handler type == 1 
[1556] AuthenNTLM: Connect to pdc = myDomainServerName bdc = myDomainServerName domain = myDomain
[1556] AuthenNTLM: enter lock
[1556] AuthenNTLM: verify handle  smbhandle == 0 
[Wed May 02 14:47:46 2012] [error] Connect to SMB Server failed (pdc = myDomainServerName bdc = myDomainServerName domain = myDomain error = -11/0) for /MyApp/searchForm.php
[1556] AuthenNTLM: leave lock
[Wed May 02 14:47:46 2012] [error] Cannot get nonce
```

Any files not "protected" my this module work fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, my bad. This had nothing to do with the upgrade. The domain server was changed and I was not notified and the 2 things in a rather weird coincidence overlapped. So simply changing domainserver to new name fixed the issue.